# Two fullscreen tkinter windows on separate monitors on Raspbery Pi 4

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi, tk-toolkit, raspberry-pi4

I have a simple TK app that runs fullscreen just fine on one monitor, but now I want to run two fullscreen windows, one on each display on a Raspberry Pi 4. The two displays have different resolutions and work fine on their own, but I can't get two fullscreen windows to work, both windows fullscreen just on the first display.

I'm trying to do it with `tkinter.Tk().geometry()`, is this the way to go or is there something more straightforward?

```
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()

# specify resolutions of both windows
w0, h0 = 3840, 2160
w1, h1 = 1920, 1080

# set up window for display on HDMI 0 
win0 = tkinter.Toplevel()
win0.geometry(f"{w0}x{h0}")
win0.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
win0.config(cursor="none") # remove cursor 
win0.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1) # make sure this window is on top 

# set up window for display on HDMI 1 
win1 = tkinter.Toplevel()
win1.geometry(f"{w1}x{h1}")
win1.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
win1.config(cursor="none")
win1.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to offset the second window to the right by the width of the first display (The X system puts the display on the `HDMI0` port down first, then puts the display from `HDMI1` to the right).`geometry` lets you make sure they don't overlap and then `fullscreen` works as expected.

The format of the `geometry` string is: `<width>x<height>+xoffset+yoffset`.

```
root = tkinter.Tk()

# specify resolutions of both windows
w0, h0 = 3840, 2160
w1, h1 = 1920, 1080

# set up window for display on HDMI 0 
win0 = tkinter.Toplevel()
win0.geometry(f"{w0}x{h0}+0+0")
win0.attributes("-fullscreen", True)

# set up window for display on HDMI 1 
win1 = tkinter.Toplevel()
win1.geometry(f"{w1}x{h1}+{w0}+0") # <- the key is shifting right by w0 here 
win1.attributes("-fullscreen", True)

root.withdraw()  # hide the empty root window
```